# Next js - AMP hybrid pages return 404

Tags: next.js

I'm building Next.js app, my main page is 'hybrid' amp page

```
export const config = { amp: 'hybrid' };

export default function Home({ data }) {...}

export async function getStaticProps() {

  return {
    props: { data: {...} },
    revalidate: 6000,
  };
}
```

I'm deploying to `serverless` using `npx serverless`

When deployed the `/index.html` home page has in its `<head>` the reference to the amp version of the page, which is `/index.amp`

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="/index.amp">
```

When I got to the amp page `/index.amp` I got 404 page

Any one know what's the problem please

```
"next": "11.0.0",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly accessing `/index.amp`, add `?amp=1` to the end of the URL you want to load the AMP version of the page.

Ref- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/amp

### Edit:

> [Ref](https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js/issues/644)- I am not aware of any AMP logic as of now, so it should be unsupported.

After lots of debugging, I found that `AMP` is not supported for the hybrid approach in `serverless-next`, although it working fine AMP-only configuration `export const config = { amp: true }`. That's the reason why it's working on localhost but not on deploy.

You can achieve this behaviour using [nextjs server-side `redirects`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects).

It's not officially supported as of version @19.0.0.

My `serverless.yml` file

```
myApp:
  component: '@sls-next/serverless-component@1.19.0'
```

### Edit 2:

Finally it's working when I don't specify version.
My changed `serverless.yml` file

```
myApp:
  component: '@sls-next/serverless-component'
```

My working deployed serverless amp version url is [here](https://d28wc8xt8wxyf0.cloudfront.net/?amp=1)

**Note**- If you do not specify the version, it will use the latest tag, which refers to the latest stable version [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sls-next/serverless-component) (i.e not alpha versions).

Comment: I tried, that's only working on `development`
and on `development` the AMP page is valid and work without errors with `?amp=1`
my problem is on production when I deploy

Comment: @WaelZoaiter Did you try `export const config = { amp: true }` to only load amp version instead of hybrid.

Comment: In dev it's working, but I didn't try deploying it, coz I need a hybrid page here

Comment: Do your filenames have uppercase letters? If yes, then change all filenames to lowercase characters then the 404 error should go away.

Comment: In that case, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on codesandbox? So I can look deeper into that.

Comment: Sorry I'm late, https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-matsumoto-dwyhp?file=/pages/index.js
This is a minimal reproducible example, but I'm afraid you may need to deploy to https://www.serverless.com/ if you want to try on production

Comment: @WaelZoaiter It's working. You can try with edited changes.

Comment: Awesome!
Could you share your `next.config.js` and the home page code, please?

Comment: I don't use `next.config.js` in my code. Only changes I did in your codesandbox code is 
1. run `npx serverless create --template aws-nodejs` in console
2. then add `serverless.yml` provided in edit2
3. and then `npx serverless` for deploy

Comment: Great Thanks!, I really appreciate your help